# Не могу извлечь данные из putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

Не могу настроить вторую активити чтоб извлечь данные из первой активити.

Нужно во второй активити извлечь соответствующий текст из:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, about.class);
            intent.putExtra("key1", R.string.tekst1);
            startActivity(intent);
            case 1:
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, about.class);
            intent2.putExtra("key1", R.string.tekst2);
            startActivity(intent1);
            case 2:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, about.class);
            inten2t.putExtra("key1", R.string.tekst3);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }
    }
});
```

как извлечь их, помогите

Comment: А как Вы извлекаете данные? Учтите, что `R.string.tekst1` - это число (типа `int`). Кстати, Вы в `switch` потеряли все `break`.

Comment: Офф.документация недостаточно подробно [описывает этот процесс](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)? Тогда какая именно проблема с извлечением и где само извлечение во второй активити? По имеющемуся коду можно только предложить вынести `startActivity()` за пределы блока switch-case, а создание экземпляра `Intent` перед блоком switch-case в целях оптимизации уменьшения дублированного кода.

Comment: разные названия создаваемых переменных и переменных, в которые добавляется Extra, это просто опечатка, я полагаю? а вообще да, неплохо бы увидеть, как извлечение происходит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, about.class);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            intent.putExtra("key1", getResource().getString(R.string.tekst1));
            break;
            case 1:
            intent.putExtra("key1", getResource().getString(R.string.tekst2));
            break ;
            case 2:
            intent.putExtra("key1", getResource ().getString(R.string.tekst3));
            break ;
        }
        startActivity (intent) ;
    }
});
```

Comment: спасиииибоооооооо!!!!!!!